# How can I capture an instance generically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using `Rails 3.2.19` and `Ruby 2.1.2`. I've been googling around trying to figure this out, but perhaps I'm not searching for the right thing. Anyway, I'll try and be as concise as possible.

I have a few different models that all have a `name` attribute. In my views I want to somehow be able to access that `name` attribute regardless of the instance name passed into the view. Currently my various controllers create instances of their respective models. For instance:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

-

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

While I understand I could simply re-name the instances something generic, I was wondering if there was some way of accessing any/all instances while maintaining unambiguous instance names.

Basically something like this:

**page.html.haml**

```
%h1= resources[0].name #equates to @page.name
%h2= @page.some_other_attribute
```

or

**product.html.haml**

```
%h1= resources[0].name #equates to @product.name
%h2= @product.price
```

Where in each of the above `resources[0]` would be either `@page` or `@product`

Comment: If you use something like `inherited_resources`, that's what it'll give you, a `resource`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out after discovering [`instance_variables`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Object/instance_variables) and [`instance_variables_get`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Object/instance_variables_get)

Those methods will return all instance variables being passed into the view. From there I discovered that the `:@_assigns` instance variable contained the instances that I was looking for. So I iterated over them to find if any had the `name` attribute.

```
- instance_variable_get(:@_assigns).each do |var|
  - if var[1].respond_to?("name")
    %h1= var[1].name
```

There is probably a better way of accomplishing this, so if anyone has any opinions, they are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define a route with an additional resource_type parameter to a generic controller or otherwise just include the resource_type into the url query parameter

```
/resources/product/17
or
/resources/17?resource_type=product
```

This will allow you to do the following in the controller

```
class ResourcesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @resource = find_resource(params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

  private
  def find_resource(params)
    resource_klass = {
      product: Product, 
      page: Page
    }[params[:resource_type]]

    resource_klass.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Another Option would be to introduce another ResourceType Entity and define a polymorphic :has_one :belongs_to association to the actual resource entity (product, page). Then always search for ResourceTypes and load the polymorphic resource entity

```
class ResourceType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :resource_type, as: :resource
end

 class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :resource_type, as: :resource
  end


product_resource_type = ResourceType.create(...)
product = Product.create(resource_type: product_resource_type)

page_resource_type = ResourceType.create(...)
page = Page.create(resource_type: page_resource_type)


ResourceType.find(product_resource_type.id).resource
=> product

ResourceType.find(page_resource_type.id).resource
=> page
```